# Prometheus kube_pod_container_status_waiting_reason not capturing pod CrashLoopBackOff reason

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager, prometheus-operator, kube-state-metrics

By definition, `kube_pod_container_status_waiting_reason` is supposed to capture  reasons for a pod in Waiting status.

I have several pods in my kubernetes cluster which are in CrashLoopBackOff but I dont see that reason captured by `kube_pod_container_status_waiting_reason`.
It only captures two reasons - ErrImagePull and ContainerCreating.

```
~$ k get pods -o wide --show-all --all-namespaces | grep Crash
cattle-system   cattle-cluster-agent-6f744c67cc-jlkjh       0/1       CrashLoopBackOff   2885       10d       10.233.121.247   k8s-4
cattle-system   cattle-node-agent-6klkh                     0/1       CrashLoopBackOff   2886       171d      10.171.201.127   k8s-2
cattle-system   cattle-node-agent-j6r94                     0/1       CrashLoopBackOff   2887       171d      10.171.201.110   k8s-3
cattle-system   cattle-node-agent-nkfcq                     0/1       CrashLoopBackOff   17775      171d      10.171.201.131   k8s-1
cattle-system   cattle-node-agent-np76b                     0/1       CrashLoopBackOff   2887       171d      10.171.201.89    k8s-4
cattle-system   cattle-node-agent-pwn5v                     0/1       CrashLoopBackOff   2859       171d      10.171.202.72    k8s-5
```

Running `sum by (reason) (kube_pod_container_status_waiting_reason)` in prometheus yields results:

```
Element                       Value
{reason="ContainerCreating"}    0
{reason="ErrImagePull"}         0
```

I am running `quay.io/coreos/kube-state-metrics:v1.2.0` image of kube-state-metrics.

What am I missing? Why is the CrashLoopBackOff reason not showing up in the query?
I would like to set up an alert which finds pods in the waiting status with the reason. So thinking of merging `kube_pod_container_status_waiting` to find the pods in the waiting status and `kube_pod_container_status_waiting_reason` to find the exact reason.

Please assist. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You are running into [this](https://github.com/kubernetes/kube-state-metrics/issues/468). Basically, it looks like you are using [kube-state-metrics](https://github.com/kubernetes/kube-state-metrics) `1.2.0` or earlier. You see that `ImagePullBackOff` and `CrashLoopBackOff` was added in `1.3.0`.

So update your image to:

```
k8s.gcr.io/kube-state-metrics:v1.3.0
quay.io/coreos/kube-state-metrics:v1.3.0
```

or

```
k8s.gcr.io/kube-state-metrics:v1.4.0
quay.io/coreos/kube-state-metrics:v1.4.0
```